# Select dropdown value by textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, dropdown

I have textarea (x1_typdv) and I want this:
If I write "3" to textarea, select option with value "3" in dropdown (x1_typdv2). I have this code but it not work, how to do it? Thanks.

```js
$('#x1_typdv').change(function() {
      $('#x1_typdv2').val($('#x1_typdv').val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="x1_typdv" value="" name="x1_typdv">


<select name="x1_typdv2" id="x1_typdv2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
   </select>
```

EDIT: I tried it again, it works for me if I use just normaln textarea. But I want use it for textarea which is filled by javascript (its calculations form), and here its not work. How to get the same value which is in teaxtarea to dropdown? Thanks.

```js
$x1_typdv    = parseFloat($('#x1_field_skrinka option:selected').attr('data-typdv')),
$x1_fieldTypdv.val($x1_typdv);
$x1_fieldTypdv = $('#x1_typdv');
```

Comment: Actually, it does work, on blur.

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/dam1tLvr/. Check the console for errors and ensure you've included jQuery in the page properly. Also note that you have to cause a blur on the `input` for the `change` event to fire

Comment: use `on input` event

Comment: check my answer please. It's a browser issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please check below answer its working..

```js
   $('#x1_typdv').keyup(function(e) { 
  if($('#x1_typdv').val()!="" && $("#x1_typdv2 option[value='"+$('#x1_typdv').val()+"']").length > 0)
        $('#x1_typdv2').val($('#x1_typdv').val());
     else if($('#x1_typdv').val()!="" && e.which != 8)
        alert("Value doesnot exists.");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="x1_typdv" value="" name="x1_typdv">


<select name="x1_typdv2" id="x1_typdv2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some browsers don't catch the *change* until *blur*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#x1_typdv').on("keyup", function() {
           $('#x1_typdv2').val($('#x1_typdv').val());
      });
});
```

EDIT: I'd also add more solidity

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#x1_typdv').on("keyup", function() {
           var value = $('#x1_typdv').val();
           value && $('#x1_typdv2').val(value);
      });
});
```

working fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/aepc4sbj/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code
using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("x1_typdv2").value = document.document.getElementById("x1_typdv").value;
```

OR

using jQuery

```
$('#x1_typdv2 option[value=' + $('#x1_typdv').val() + ']').attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add jquery in your page and try this code :

```
$('#x1_typdv').on('change', function() {
  $('#x1_typdv2').val($('#x1_typdv').val());
});
```